# DrawLines draws an extra unwanted line

Tags: c#, forms, gdi+

My application saves points in an array and then calls `System.Drawing.Graphic.DrawLines(Pen, Point[])` to draw the lines connecting the points. It works, but drawlines always seems to place an extra line between the first point of the array and the upper left corner of the form.

ok wait a sec, i did a mess with the samples, fixing it as soon as possible

Code sample:

```
Pen black = new Pen(Color.black, 2);
MyGraphicObject = Graphics.FromImage(picture);
Point[] linee = new Point[5];
public void check (int a, int b)
{         
     linee[0].X = (b) * 30 + 13;
     linee[0].Y = (a-1) * 30 + 13; 
     linee[1].X = (b+1) * 30 + 13;
     linee[1].Y = (a) * 30 + 13; 
     linee[2].X = (b) * 30 + 13;
     linee[2].Y = (a+1) * 30 + 13; 
     linee[3].X = (b-1) * 30 + 13;
     linee[3].Y = (a) * 30 + 13; 
     linee[4].X = (b) * 30 + 13;
     linee[4].Y = (a-1) * 30 + 13; 
     MyGraphicObject.DrawLines(black, linee);
}
```

Image with the problem

[image]

Comment: Please post the code as text, rather than as an image.

Comment: It's funny how you declare an array with size 4 and fill it with 5 values...

Comment: @JonB He said he has problems posting it as text (but omitted which problems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Graphics.DrawLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ewkcdb3.aspx) method:

> draws a series of lines connecting an array of ending points. The
>   first two points in the array specify the first line. Each additional
>   point specifies the end of a line segment whose starting point is the
>   ending point of the previous line segment.

I think you have one extra point either at beginning or at the end of array, which is initialized with default value. Possible reason - you create array of points which has N+1 length (where N is points number). And you don't provide X and Y for first or last point. Thus it stays with default `X = 0, Y = 0`

Comment: Oh i see, that' s my problem. Should' ve checked better before asking.